# How can I get an Account's contact email based on another custom object?

Tags: reporting

I have a custom object called: license, with a Lookup relation to Account.
Based on some filters I do for the account, I want to get a list of licenses, as well as a list of email (or contact info)

- the regular report objects do not give me such an option
- joined reports can not help me here
- I want to try and avoid from using several different reports, and join with 3rd party.

thanks

Comment: You need to see, for each Account, a list of license rows and a list of Contact rows. It sounds like you're describing a joined report, joining a report on Accounts with Licenses to a report based on Accounts with Contacts. What is the reason they're not helping you?

Comment: I need to merge the filters from both reports. so report A with filter a, and only those results for them I need to know the contact information.

Comment: Above you say your filters are on Account, but you mean to say that there are filters on which contacts are displayed as well? Or do you mean that based on information in licenses, you need to see Contacts?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham you are correct. Based on the filter results from licenses, I want to see the contacts that are linked to that account.

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the relationship on License from Lookup to Master-Detail, you may be able to rollup your filter conditions to a Rollup Summary Field on Account, and then use that summary field to do your filtering. This depends on what your filters on License are specifically.

For example, if you want to only show Accounts where there is at least one License with Active__c = TRUE, you can use a Number formula field on License: `IF(Active__c == TRUE,1,0)`. Then create a Roll-up Summary Field (called "Total Active Licenses" maybe) on Account that shows you `SUM(Active__c)` from Licenses. This field now identifies how many Licenses on your Account are Active. Your report will then filter on showing Accounts where `Total Active Licenses > 0`.

If there is a reason this relationship cannot be Master-Detail, then this functionality can only be accomplished through an Apex Trigger.

Comment: Thanks. relation ship can NOT be changed to M-D. Nice idea with the triggers. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go for VF pages as you can't query the child object's data from a parent object through the reports.. A custom related list developed thru vf pages will help you here probably